# scala not on path after installing typesafe-stack on Ubuntu

Tags: scala, typesafe-stack

On Ubuntu 12.04, I have installed typesafe-stack following the instructions [here](http://typesafe.com/stack/download).

After doing so, I do not have `scala` or `scalac` on my PATH. I do have `sbt`, and I can run `console` from there, but I do not have any native Scala executables installed.

Where is `scalac` supposed to be installed? Why has it not been so? How do I fix it?

Comment: have you issued `sudo apt-get install scala`?

Answer (score 2):

The Typesafe stack for Debian-based systems doesn't come with Scala itself, so you have to install it manually:

```
sudo aptitude install scala -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala is compiled into Java bytecode (or .NET CLR if you want to), so technically there's no need to have the binary installed. Sbt downloads and installs the Scala Compiler on first run or so, that's why things like `sbt`, `sbt console` and even running `Play 2` applications works.

To get the interpreter, use `apt-get` as mentioned above, the version is different from the one the Typesafe Stack uses (2.9.2 vs. 2.9.1), but I did not have any trouble so far. Seems like sbt is using the correct version defined for the project and even dependencies are stored separately (just check `~/.ivy/cache` to see what I mean)